# ios newsstand behaviour when a remote nofication is received whilst on 3G (not wifi)

Tags: ios, newsstand-kit

The newsstand framework will only handle downloads for you when you are on wifi, but it's not very clear what happens over a 3G cellular network.
Here is the scenario:

My app is running in the background when it receives a remote notification telling it that new content is available and is not connected to wifi at the time.

I create a new NKIssue and a NKAssetDownload for that issue (a zip file containing all I need for that issue).

I call `[asset downloadWithDelegate:self];`

From what I can tell, the asset does not get downloaded - even when I connect to wifi later on, the asset never gets downloaded and if I query the `downloadingAssets` of NKIssue, it is an empty array.

So it appears there is no way to get back my asset object to start the download again (assuming now on wifi).

I could keep a separate reference to the asset object around to restart its download, or could create a new NKAssetDownload object (where did the existing one go?) or could check whether I'm on 3G/wifi when the remote notification comes in and branch in my code accordingly or something else(?), but I feel like I'm missing something. The documentation seems incomplete here too.

Has anyone found a good way of dealing with this?

Comment: now realise there is also a `downloadingAssets` property on NKLibrary as well as NKIssue, but I'm finding this an empty array too.

Comment: Are you resuming your downloads in applicationDidFinishLauncingWithoptions? Your download should start if app launches when connected in wifi

Comment: @MSK Well that's the problem, to restart my downloads, I need a reference to them, but the `downloadingAssets` array is empty..

Comment: I think iOS should hold the "content-available" notification until iPad is not connect to wifi. That means your call to [asset downloadWithDelegate:self]; should happen when in wifi only. If it is not the case then [NKLibrary downloadingAssets].count should be > 0 in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method if NOT then it could be a bug in the way NS is implemented.